# random color text generate

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a program in python that will accept an argument of text input, then randomly change each letter to be a different color

This is what I have:

```
color = ['red' , 'blue', 'green' , 'purple' , 'yellow' , 'pink' , '#f60' , 'black' , 'white'];
```

I want to be able to have a program that can let me type out a paragraph, then it uses the colors in the list and randomly assigns them to each letter.

For an output, I would like to to be something like this.

```
[color=random]H[/color][color=random]i[/color] [color=random]t[/color] [color=random]h[/color] [color=random]e[/color][color=random]r[/color][color=random]e[/color]
```

The colors should be random from the list I made. Is this possible to make?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
from random import choice

color = ['red' , 'blue', 'green' , 'purple' , 'yellow' , 'pink' , '#f60' , 'black' , 'white']
l = len(color)

str = "Hit Here"

html = ''
for x in str:
    html += '[color=' + choice(color) + ']' + x + '[/color]' if len(x.strip()) > 0 else x

print(html)
```

Sample output:

```
[color=yellow]H[/color][color=#f60]i[/color][color=yellow]t[/color] [color=black]H[/color][color=black]e[/color][color=white]r[/color][color=purple]e[/color]

[color=purple]H[/color][color=white]i[/color][color=purple]t[/color] [color=black]H[/color][color=green]e[/color][color=red]r[/color][color=blue]e[/color]

[color=yellow]H[/color][color=green]i[/color][color=#f60]t[/color] [color=blue]H[/color][color=white]e[/color][color=green]r[/color][color=pink]e[/color]
```

Comment: Edited answer using choice function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

pip install pygments, then try this:

```
import random
from pygments.console import codes
string='some string here'
print ''.join([random.choice(codes.values())+x+codes['reset'] for x in string])
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
import random

#console color
W  = '\033[0m'  # white (normal)
R  = '\033[31m' # red
G  = '\033[32m' # green
O  = '\033[33m' # orange
B  = '\033[34m' # blue
P  = '\033[35m' # purple

my_color = [W, R, G, O, B, P]

a = raw_input("Enter your text to be colourful: ")
new_text =""
for x in a:
    new_text += x + random.choice(my_color)

print new_text + W
```

[image]

your Desired output:

```
>>> import random
>>> color = ['red' , 'blue', 'green' , 'purple' , 'yellow' , 'pink' , '#f60' , 'black' , 'white']
>>> new_text = ""
>>> import random
>>> for x in text:
...     new_text += "[color={}]{}[/color]".format(random.choice(color), x)
... 
>>> new_text
'[color=#f60]h[/color][color=white]e[/color][color=blue]l[/color][color=#f60]l[/color][color=black]o[/color][color=white] [/color][color=purple]h[/color][color=white]o[/color][color=green]w[/color][color=pink] [/color][color=white]a[/color][color=white]r[/color][color=yellow]e[/color][color=red] [/color][color=#f60]y[/color][color=green]o[/color][color=red]u[/color]'
```